# Difference between 'One to One' and 'One on One'?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, difference, word-difference

I've had this confusion for a long time: what is the difference between *one to one* and *one on one*?

Which one is more appropriate:

> We will have *one to one* meeting?
>
> We will have *one on one* meeting?